# Can't sort array items by value ASC

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I get all keywords separated by commas from database and create arrays from them then I merge all arrays. From the resulted array I keep only unique items `array_unique`. The problem is that I can't sort resulted array by value.

Here is my code:

```
$select_all_keywords = mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT `keywords` FROM `bookmarks`") or die(mysqli_error());

$keywords_array = array();

while($keywords = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_keywords))
{
    $explode_keywords = explode(", ", $keywords['keywords']);
    $keywords_array = array_merge($keywords_array, $explode_keywords);
}

$unique_keywords = array_unique($keywords_array);

sort($unique_keywords);

$unique_keywords = array_values($unique_keywords);

print_array($unique_keywords);
```

The printed array:

```
array(23) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "Awolnation"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Belgium"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "Gravity"
  [3]=>
  string(21) "Nervo (Musical Group)"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "R3..."
  [5]=>
  string(22) "R3hab (Musical Artist)"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "Remix"
  [7]=>
  string(4) "Sail"
  [8]=>
  string(30) "Tomorrowland (Recurring Event)"
  [9]=>
  string(21) "Tomorrowland Festival"
  [10]=>
  string(9) "Unlimited"
  [11]=>
  string(6) "dasdas"
  [12]=>
  string(10) "freshbooks"
  [13]=>
  string(11) "gdsfgdsfgds"
  [14]=>
  string(6) "mockup"
  [15]=>
  string(3) "php"
  [16]=>
  string(11) "programming"
  [17]=>
  string(10) "revolution"
  [18]=>
  string(17) "tomorrowland 2013"
  [19]=>
  string(11) "ummet ozcan"
  [20]=>
  string(10) "web design"
  [21]=>
  string(7) "wikihow"
  [22]=>
  string(3) "xml"
}
```

I tryed almost all sorting array functions. None of them helped me sort the array by value ASC.

Comment: Oooof, for one-to-many relationships you shouldn't be storing them in a single table.

Comment: Why the `$unique_keywords = array_values($unique_keywords);`?

Comment: @geomagas I also need those keywords for an autocomplete script and I need to 'json_encode' array. Without the 'array_values' the array is displayed not only the values, also the keys, and I need only the values for autocomplete.

Comment: What happens if you comment out that line? Does `sort()` work?

Comment: @geomagas Sorry, I pressed enter and my comment was submitted before I finished what I wanted to write.

Comment: Happens all the time. So what about commenting out that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you might be looking for asort(), it will sort the array by value. But still keep the keys the same.

Look at the documentation here. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: What is it returning? 

You could also try natcasesort http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php